# scalajs-react router. How to perform ajax request inside conditional route

Tags: scala, routes, scala.js, scalajs-react

I am trying to make some conditional routes. The condition resolves on the serverside. 

Route rule example:

```
| (dynamicRouteCT("#user" / long.caseClass[User]) ~> dynRender((page: User) => <.div("Hello, " + page.id.toString)))
  .addCondition((page: User) => checkPermissions(page.id))(_ => Some(redirectToPage(Page403)(Redirect.Push)))
```

`checkpermissions` body:

```
  def checkPermissions(id: Long) = CallbackTo.future{
    /*Ajax.get(s"http://some.uri/?id=$id") map (res =>
     * if (something) true
     * else false
     * )
     */

    //the request before returns Future[XMLHttprequest] witch maps to Future[Boolean]
    Future(false)
  }
```

I got type missmatch here: `(page: User) => checkPermissions(page.id)`

Is it possible to perform ajax request inside conditional routes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we look at `def addCondition(cond: Page => CallbackTo[Boolean])(condUnmet: Page => Option[Action[Page]]): Rule[Page]` we can see that it requires a `CallbackTo[Boolean]`. Because of the nature of the JS env, there is now way to go from `Future[A]` to `A`. Although it's not a limitation from scalajs-react itself, it is an inherited reality that will affect your scalajs-react code; as [this table in the doc](https://github.com/japgolly/scalajs-react/blob/master/doc/CALLBACK.md#callbacks-and-futures) shows, there's no way to go from a `CallbackTo[Future[Boolean]]` to a `CallbackTo[Boolean]`.

This type-level restriction is actually a really good thing for user experience. The router is synchronous, it must determine how to render routes and route changes immediately. If it were allowed to be async and somehow supported `Future`s, then the user would experience noticable (and potentially huge) delays without any kind of visual feedback or means of interruption.

The "right way" to solve this problem is to use a model that covers the async state. This is what I would do:

1. Create an `AsyncState[E, A]` ADT with cases: `Empty`, `AwaitingResponse`, `Loaded(value: A)`, `Failed(error: E)`.
   *(You can enrich these further if desired, eg. loadTime on `Loaded`, retry callback on `Failed`, timeStarted on `AwaitingResponse`, etc.)*
2. Have an instance of `AsyncState[Boolean]` in your (local/client-side) state.
3. Optionally kick-off an async load on page startup.
4. Have the router pass its value to a component and/or check the value of this.
   *(The router won't know the value because it's dynamic, use `Callback` in a for-comprehension to wire things up and satisfy the types.)*
5. Depending on the value of `AsyncState[Boolean]`, render something meaningful to the user. If it's `AwaitingResponse`, display a little spinner; if it's failed display an error and probably a retry button.

(It should also be noted that `AsyncState[Boolean]` shouldn't actually be `Boolean` as that's not very descriptive or true to the domain. It would probably be something more meaningful like `AsyncState[UserAccess]` or something like that.)

Hope that helps! Good luck!